# Do equal limits from orthogonal directions imply the limit of the function?

Tags: limits

If a function approaches the same limit from orthogonal directions, does the limit then exist?

For example, take $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ where $f(z)=\frac{\sin{z}}{z}$. Does the fact that $$\lim_{t \to 0}f(t)=1=\lim_{t \to 0}f(it)$$ imply that $$\lim_{z \to (0,0)}f(z)=1?$$

Comment: No. For example, consider $f(re^{i\theta}) = \sin (2\theta)$.

Comment: What/s even worse, there are functions that have the same limit along EVERY straight line direction, and the limit still doesn't exist because there is a different limit on curved paths

Comment: Could you give an example? Or better yet a hint as to how I could arrive at one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely not.  Consider the function:

$$f(z) = \begin{cases} 1 \quad \text{ if z lies on the real or imaginary axis}\\ 
0 \ \quad \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Obviously $\displaystyle \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} f(t + 0i) = \lim_{t \rightarrow 0} f(0 + it) = 1$.  However, $\displaystyle \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} f(z)$ cannot possibly exist: If we take $\displaystyle \varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, then there exists no $\delta$-ball around the origin that would guarantee $|1 - f(w)| < \varepsilon$ for **all** $w \in B_\delta(0)$.

Comment: Good and simple counter example. Should have seen that. Though I still find it difficult to conceptualize (without a graphing program) functions like $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$, which has no limit at (0,0) despite being continuous in every neighborhood around (0,0) and finite from every direction.

Comment: Oh me too @dimwatt.  It's somewhat unbelievable to me, but I have faith in the calculus.

Answer (score 1):

A simple counterexample in real numbers: $\frac {xy} {x^2+y^2}$. The limits along the coordinate axes are $0$, yet this function has no limit (try $y=tx$; the result will depend on $t$).